# How to read a singly linked list backwards?

Tags: c#, singly-linked-list

One method which I can think of is to reverse the list and then read it.
But this involves changing the list which is bad.
OR I can make a copy of the list and then reverse it, but this uses additional O(n) memory.
Is there any better method which doesn't use extra memory and doesn't modify the list and runs in O(n) time

reverse linked list code is something like this in c#

```
Void Reverse (Node head)
{
    Node prev= null;
    Node current = head;
    Node nextNode = null;

        while (current!=null)
        {
            nextNode = current.Next;
            current.Next = prev;
            prev=current;
            current = nextNode; 

        }
        head = prev;

}
```

Recursive solution is

```
void ReadBackWard (Node n)
{
    if (n==null)
        return;
    else
        ReadBackward(n.Next);

    Console.WriteLine(n.Data);

}
```

Comment: Recursion is your friend

Comment: @Neil: Can you suggest some pseudo code using recursion

Comment: But recursion uses O(n) memory

Comment: From below answers we can solve this in O(n) time only if we use O(n) extra memory. See answers below....
Thanks guys for all the help....SO is really awesome and you guys rock !!!....

Comment: Neil: Check my recursive implementation

Comment: Recursion will still use O(n) extra memory. Event worse, it's stack memory, which you usually don't have very much of.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To use O(n) memory and O(n) performance, create a stack; push everything on as you iterate  in the forwards direction, then pop everything off, yielding the results.

To use O(n^2) performance (but O(1) extra memory), read it forwards each time, up the the node before the last one you got to.

Example:

```
IEnumerable<T> Reverse (Node head) {
    Stack<Node> nodes = new Stack<Node>();
    while(head != null) {
        nodes.Push(head);
        head = head.Next;
    }
    while(nodes.Count > 0) {
        yield return nodes.Pop().Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is equivalent to creating a reversed copy of the list.

Comment: this is a better solution, but it uses same O(n) memory, which is same as having a copy of list and reversing it and reading it

Comment: Not necessarily. You only have to push the pointers onto the stack, not the entire items.

Comment: This is fundamentally identical to recursion.  The only difference is an explicit stack vs. recursion's implicit stack.

Comment: With recursion you also typically need to push additional state representing the call position. Using an explicit stack is *generally* more efficient.

Comment: @Marc By "call position" you presumably mean "return address"?

Comment: The combination of return address and the next node address, depending on the implementation.

Answer (score 11):

One of the hallmarks of a singly-linked list is that it is, in fact, singly linked. It is a one-way street, and there's no way to overcome that unless you turn it into something else (such as a reversed singly-linked list, a stack, a doubly-linked list...). One must be true to the nature of things.

As has been pointed out earlier; if you need to traverse a list both ways; you need to have a doubly-linked list. That is the nature of a doubly linked list, it goes both ways.

Comment: +1 sigh.  Why is simplicity, which is championed by those who built SO, so verily ignored?

Answer (score 8):

Really you should be using a doubly-linked list.

If this isn't possible, I think your best option will be to construct a copy of the list that has been reversed.

Other options, such as relying on recursion (effectively copying the list to the stack) could cause you to run out of stack space if the list is too long.

Comment: See tag - "interview-questions" :)

Comment: I think changing the list to a doubly linked list is less bad that coming up with other mechanisms to fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you short of memory you can reverse list, iterate over it and reverse it again. Alternatively you can make a stack of pointers to nodes (or whatever is like a pointer in C#).

Answer (score 3):

There is a third solution, this time using `O(log(n))` memory and `O(n log(n))` time, thus occupying the middle ground between the two solutions in Marc's answer.

It is effectively a reverse in-order descent of a binary tree [`O(log(n))`], except at each step you need to find the top of the tree [`O(n)`]:

1. Split the list in two
2. Recurse into the second half of the list
3. Print the value at the midpoint
4. Recurse into the first half

Here is the solution in Python (I don't know C#):

```
def findMidpoint(head, tail):
  pos, mid = head, head
  while pos is not tail and pos.next is not tail:
    pos, mid = pos.next.next, mid.next
  return mid

def printReversed(head, tail=None):
  if head is not tail:
    mid = findMidpoint(head, tail)
    printReversed(mid.next, tail)
    print mid.value,
    printReversed(head, mid)
```

This could be recast using iteration instead of recursion, but at the cost of clarity.

For example, for a million-entry list, the three solutions take on the order of:

```
Solution   Memory       Performance
=========================================
 Marc #1     4MB    1 million operations
  Mine       80B    20 million operations
 Marc #2      4B    1 trillion operations
```

Comment: @chrispy: A tree with `n` nodes needs `O(n)` memory and not `O(log n)` as you have mentioned. Did I understand something wrong?

Comment: @eSKay The code is traversing the list _as if_ there was an associated tree, not actually creating the tree in memory

Comment: @Lazer: Ignore the word "tree", and think in terms of divide-and-conquer: if you keep track of the halfway point, you can process the second half of the list just as efficiently as the first half.  In processing the first second of the list, if you keep track of the 3/4 point, you can process the four quarter as quickly as the third quarter.  Then when processing the first half, keep the 1/4 point so you can process the second quarter as efficiently as the first.

Comment: Beautiful solution!

Answer (score 3):

```
void reverse_print(node *head) 
{
    node *newHead = NULL, *cur = head;

    if(!head) return;

    // Reverse the link list O(n) time O(1) space
    while(cur){
        head = head->next;
        cur->next = newHead;
        newHead = cur;
        cur = head;
    }

    // Print the list O(n) time O(1) space
    cur = newHead;
    while(cur) {
        printf(" %d", cur->val);
        cur = cur->next;
    }

    // Reverse the link list again O(n) time O(1) space
    cur = newHead;
    while(cur){
        newHead = newHead->next;
        cur->next = head;
        head = cur;
        cur = newHead;
    }
    // Total complexity O(n) time O(1) space
}
```

Comment: best algo for reverse printing, saves time and space

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your singly-linked list implements IEnumerable<T>, you can utilize LINQ's Reverse extension method:

```
var backwards = singlyLinkedList.Reverse();
```

You'll need to add a `using System.Linq;` directive at the top of the code file to use LINQ's extension methods.

Comment: ... Which is exactly what the OP suggested but wanted a better solution than. Just because you don't allocate the extra memory yourself does not mean it doesn't happen.

Comment: Reverse is lazily-loaded, executed when the items are requested. It's not the same as the OP.

Answer (score 1):

A variation of creating a stack and pushing all the elements onto the stack is to use recursion (and the system's built in stack), this is probably not the way to go with production code but serves as a better (IMHO) interview answer for the following reasons:

1. It shows that you grok recursion
2. It's less code and appears more elegant
3. A naive interviewer may not realize that there is a space overhead (if this is the case you may want to consider whether you want to work there).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the naive solution would be to keep track of which node you're currently at, then iterate from the start until you find that node, always saving the node you just left. Then each time you find the node you're currently at, you produce the node you just left, save that node as the one you're currently at, then re-iterate from the start.

This would of course be horribly bad performance-wise.

I'm sure some smarter people have a better solution.

Pseudo-code (with bugs even):

```
current node = nothing
while current node is not first node
    node = start
    while node is not current node
        previous node = node
        node = next node
    produce previous node
    set current node to previous node
```

Answer (score 0):

This is messy but works:

```
class SinglyLinkedList {
SinglyLinkedList next;
int pos;
SinglyLinkedList(int pos) {
    this.pos = pos;
}
SinglyLinkedList previous(SinglyLinkedList startNode) {
    if (startNode == this) return null;
    if (startNode.next == this) return startNode;
    else return previous(startNode.next);
}

static int count = 0;
static SinglyLinkedList list;
static SinglyLinkedList head;
static SinglyLinkedList tail;
public static void main (String [] args) {
    init();

    System.out.println("Head: " + head.pos);
    System.out.println("Tail: " + tail.pos);

    list = head;
    System.out.print("List forwards: ");
    while (list != null) {
        System.out.print(list.pos + ",");
        list = list.next;
    }

    list = tail;
    System.out.print("\nList backwards: ");
    while (list.previous(head) != null) {
        System.out.print(list.pos + ",");
        list = list.previous(head);
    }
}
static void init() {
    list = new SinglyLinkedList(0);
    head = list;
    while (count < 100) {
        list.next = new SinglyLinkedList(++count);
        list = list.next;
    }
    tail = list;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If in the Explicit Stack program, we create a stack for just the data of each node (instead of creating the Stack of type `<Node>`, we create Stack of type `<T>`) wouldn't it be even better? Because we don't need to store any other information of the Node then.

```
IEnumerable<T> Reverse (Node<T> head) {
    Stack<T> nodes = new Stack<T>();
    while(head != null) {
        nodes.Push(head.data);
        head = head.Next;
    }
    while(nodes.Count > 0) {
        yield return nodes.Pop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you could read it in O(n^2) -- every time go to the last node read and print out the previous one

Answer (score -1):

What's wrong with:

```
    public void printBackwards(LinkedList sl){    
        ListIterator<Element> litr = sl.listIterator(sl.size());
        Element temp;
        while(litr.previousIndex() >= 0){
            temp = litr.previous();
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }
```

O(n) performance, O(1) memory and simple as do-re-mi!

Comment: Down voted; Linked list in C# is implemented as a doubly linked list, and the OP is asking for a singly linked list.