# Reverse the elements of a list using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, list, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read a singly linked list backwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116720/how-to-read-a-singly-linked-list-backwards)
>   [Reverse a LinkedList c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033592/reverse-a-linkedlist-c)

How can I `reverse` the elements of a connected `list` without using `arrays`

(I have to use only pointers thats my problem).

Comment: "I have to use only pointers thats my problem" - raw pointers? Then you're writing C. Regarding your question, if it's a singly linked list, then you can't avoid O(n) complexity, by traversing it once. If it's a doubly linked list, then you can just traverse it in the opposite direction.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13033927/596781) helps...

Comment: @MihaiTodor So STL/Boost aren't C++? Come off it.

Comment: @James He did not show us any code, so I made an assumption. As far as STL is concerned, its containers are type safe and exception safe. Anyway, this is off topic.

Comment: @MihaiTodor I mean I have to use pointers in order to reverse the list.I have thought of a solution to reverse it but I have to use arrays and I am not allowed to do that.So thats why I am asking for an example on how to do it  so I can go on with  this exercise.                                                       Thanks everyone else for your help I will study the answers you gave me and  see what I can make out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You need neither to swap node *content* or a stack. If you want to reverse a single-linked list just walk it with a pair of pointers plus on intermediate pointer within the iterative loop. Don't forget to update the head pointer when you're finished;

```
void reverse_list(node **head)
{
    node *cur=NULL, *nxt=NULL;

    if (!(head || *head || (*head)->next))
        return;

    nxt = *head;
    while (nxt != NULL)
    {
        node *prv = cur;
        cur = nxt;
        nxt = nxt->next;
        cur->next = prv;
    }

    *head = cur;
}
```

Assuming the list node is something like this:

```
typedef struct node
{
    ..data..
    struct node *next;
} node;
```

and it is properly managed, then you invoke as such:

```
node *head = NULL;

...fill the list...

reverse_list(&head);
```

Answer (score 0):

Treat the list like a stack, pop the elements off and push them into a new list.

Comment: I think he would rather do the operation more "in-place", in order to to preserve memory. For this, he will need two auxiliary pointers to the current and previous node, and update the links between the nodes while traversing the list once.

Answer (score 0):

Conside a list called `lst` which allows us to move forward backward i.e it is `doubly linked list`

You can reverse the list `lst` by simply swapping the content of the beginning and the end nodes

```
void reverse(lst *beg,lst *end)
{
    lst temp;
    while(beg!=end)
    {
        //swap the content of the nodes
        *temp=*beg;
        *beg=*end;
        *end=*temp;

        beg=beg->Next();//move to next node
        end=end->prev();//move to previous node
    }
}
```

---

**OR**

---

If its a `singly linked list`,you can use `stack`

```
void reverse(lst* beg)
{
    stack<lst*> stc;
    lst* temp=beg;
    lst* temp1=beg;
    while(temp)//store pointers to lst nodes in stack
    {
        stc.push(temp);
        temp=temp.Next();
    }
    while(temp1)//pop the stack by inserting it into list from beginning
    {
       *temp1=*stc.top();
        temp1=temp1.Next(); 
        stc.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Simply use the list container class of c++" - He might not want that, since it is implemented as a doubly linked list, which is not always the best choice for performance-tight code.